# Opencv with both TBB and IPP

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection, tbb

I have build Opencv With TBB enabled. And used "detectMultiscale" and wrote a basic program to detect the face. I couldnt find any changes in processing time if there is a face in a frame. Also i noticed that the processing time has been reduced by two times if there is no face in  a frame(empty).

1) How to improve the processing time now?

2) Is it worth to go for Intel IPP? What could be the actual benefit?

Can anyone give me an advice?

### Update:

I did this with opencv2.4.5.

### Update 2:

I Posted the same question in opencv community and got the reply as TBB is pre-enabled from opencv2.4.5 and we doesnt need to re-build opencv with TBB enbled? Is that correct?

http://answers.opencv.org/question/14226/opencv-with-both-tbb-and-ipp/?answer=14231#post-id-14231

Answer (score 6):

Use of the IPP is rather depreciated, and is really only in OpenCV for historic reasons (i.e. when OpenCV was an Intel Library!)

As per the most recent [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html?highlight=ipp), what little benefit remains...

> ``may be used to improve the performance of color conversion, Haar
>   training and DFT functions of the OpenCV library.''

So you *might* get some benefit from it - but crucially rememember the IPP library **is not free**.

Since you are already using the TBB (which is itself rather redundant these days - especially on Windows version of OpenCV) the only real gains may be in using the [GPU](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/modules/gpu/doc/gpu.html) or [OpenCL](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/modules/ocl/doc/ocl.html) modules.

And of those, assuming you are working in C++, the OpenCL really represents the most up-to-date and accessible way of incorporating further speed-up (transparent of processor/gpu configuration).

Since you are doing face detection I guess you might have beeing using the Haar classifier functionality (doesn't everyone:-). In which case, you may want to try the [OpenCL version](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/modules/ocl/doc/object_detection.html) instead...

Comment: + Thanks for your answer. Can you see my update. Is the answer in this link correct?http://answers.opencv.org/question/14226/opencv-with-both-tbb-and-ipp/?answer=14231#post-id-14231

Comment: That is certainly correct with regards to the most recent Windows distributions of OpenCV (the versions I have used) - since the tbb.dll is bundled and is requirement of the pre-built OpenCV DLLs. So, in other-words if you are using the Windows lib distribution it is included - but if you were to build it from scratch/git yourself, you would require to have a version of the TBB on the include/lib paths, etc.